# Geometric interpretation of cross & dot product relation

Tags: vectors

May be simple, but how is each term geometrically interpreted in a comprehensive diagram?

We have a Pythagorean relation between dot and cross products here, so how draw it in the plane?

$$|a \times  b|^2 + (a.b)^2 = |a |^2 | b|^2. $$

EDIT1:

Trying to depict dot product norm , cross product norm and product of each of two norms in a Pythagorean semi-circle diagram. Cross product is a diagonal of a parallelogram, but dot product is a scalar...

Comment: $|a \times b| = |a| |b| \sin\theta$ and $|a \cdot b| = |a| |b| \cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I meant the relation that I have given last line.

Comment: Yes, $|a \times b|^2 + (a \cdot b)^2 = |a \times b|^2 + |a \cdot b|^2 = (|a| |b| \sin\theta)^2 + (|a| |b| \cos\theta)^2 = |a|^2 |b|^2 (\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta) = |a|^2 |b|^2$

Comment: I wish them depicted  in a diagram as mentioned in edit.

Comment: I don't know how to depict $a \cdot b$, especially not in a vector space.

Comment: Me too, so I posted this,  I feel it of mathematical significance especially with the cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: cross dot identity]

Given an arbitrary chosen point and vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

- Let $A$ be the point with $\vec{OA} = \vec{a}$ and $B$ be the point with $\vec{OB} = \vec{b}$.
- Construct a parallelogram with $O$, $A$, $B$ as vertices. let $C$ be the remaining vertex.
- Perpendicular project $A$ and $C$ onto the line $OB$ and let the feet be $A'$ and $C'$ respectively.

  We can slide the bottom edge $OB$ of the parallelogram $OBCA$ along the line
  $OB$ while keeping the top edge $AC$ fixed. When $OB$ reaches the position of $A'C'$, we obtain an rectangle $AA'C'C$ with same area $|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}|$ as parallelogram $OBCA$.
- On the plane holding the line $OB$ perpendicular to the axis $AA'$. Rotate 
  $O$ with respect to $A'$ for $90^\circ$ to get the point $O'$. Similarly, rotate $B$ with respect to $C'$ for $90^\circ$ to get the point $B'$.
  Since $|A'O| = |A'O'|$ and $|AO| = |AO'|$, rectangle $A'O'B'C'$ has area $|\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}|$ and rectangle $AO'B'C$ has area $|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|$.

For all three rectangles $AA'C'C$, $A'O'B'C'$, $AO'B'C$, one of their side has length $|A'C'| = |OB|$. This implies

$$ \begin{align}
|\vec{a} \times \vec{b} | : |\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}| : |\vec{a}||\vec{b}|
& = \verb/Area/(AA'C'C) : \verb/Area/(A'O'B'C') : \verb/Area/(AO'B'C)\\
& = |AA'| : |A'O'| : |AO'|
\end{align}
$$
Since triangle $AA'O'$ is an right angle triangle, by Pythagorean theorem, we have
$$|AA'|^2 + |A'O'|^2 = |AO'|^2
\quad\implies\quad
|\vec{a} \times \vec{b} |^2 + |\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}|^2 = |\vec{a}|^2|\vec{b}|^2$$

Comment: What program have you used to draw that image?

Comment: @md2perpe I draw the image in Geogebra (the 2D version. I fake the 3D image by hand, that's why the aspect ratio looks a little bit off).

Answer (score 0):

Taking it easy,  wlog let $ \bar b =1$ be a unit vector aligned  in direction of $a$. Angle between vectors $a,b$ is $\theta$ and we have for absolute value of cross product

$$ DotPr = a\cos \theta,\, CrossProd = a\sin \theta,\, ScalarProd= a \,$$

seen in Pythagorean setting :

[image: DotCrossProds]